# Encodings: OS, keyboard input etc

Tags: windows, unicode, encoding, keyboard, operating-system

I'm trying to understand how operating systems deal with different encodings. I have read that Windows uses UTF-16 internally. If I type text into a text editor, is it going to be saved in UTF-16 on the hard disk on Windows? Is the text typed in (and temporarily stored in RAM until saved) encoded in the OS's internal encoding unless explicitly converted by a text editor with such capability? If I create a UTF-8 SQL database, but fill it with text using my keyboard on Windows, is the OS pushing UTF-16 encoded text inside or does the system at some point realise that it should be UTF-8? When I make webpages I'm told that it's best to use UTF-8. So I make sure that my text editors are set to that, but how do I know that the input from the keyboard/OS is UTF-8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Unicode charset can be represented with many encodings, chief among them: utf-8, utf-16 and utf-32. The software you use will translate between different charsets and encodings internally as appropriate, though you might have to select the input and output encodings for permanent storage (files) yourself.

Because Windows created a whole new suite of wide APIs when people thought UTF-16 would stay UCS2 forever, most Windows components internally use UTF-16. Also, the narrow APIs are generally more restricted, where they exist at all, and generally use some obsolete ANSI codepage, not UTF-8. Thus, if your editor was originally developed on Windows, or uses a Windows standard control for text display and editing, your text will (mostly transparent to you) be UTF-16 in memory.

Most text editors (including Windows Editor) still save text per default as UTF-8. Microsoft editors (and much more windows software) though tend to prefix any Unicode text file with a BOM, which can make non-BOM-aware software choke.